# How to configure .env file to send mails in production using laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, email, configuration

Please I want to know how to configure the .env file snippet below

```
     MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
     MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
     MAIL_PORT=2525
     MAIL_USERNAME=null
     MAIL_PASSWORD=null
     MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The smptp driver and maitrap as I know is only for development.

Please what is the correct configuration to use; which mail driver, host etc. 
I'm uploading to namecheap server.

Comment: What email address would you like to add? Is the email from your own domain or maybe gmail yahoo or anything?

Comment: One from my domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still send emails with smtp while in production. This is how you should configure the .env file

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 # You will have to find your own server address and use it instead of server126.web-hosting.com 
 MAIL_HOST=server126.web-hosting.com 
 MAIL_PORT=465     
 MAIL_USERNAME=your_namecheap_username
 MAIL_PASSWORD=your_namecheap_password
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

For more details on configurations and finding your server details [click here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9142/2186/general-configuration-for-mail-clients-and-mobile-devices)